# Scaling of a quad is incorrect after resizing the window. How to fix?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

If I try to render a square with the same scaling for x and y without resizing the window everything is fine. But after resizing the window there is no longer a square rendered. Instead, you can see a rectangle, even though I am recalculating the projection matrix and passing the matrix to the shader every time the window's width or height changes.
With a different width and height, the scaling of a square is incorrect. Changing the size of the window in my code without resizing the window does not change the scaling.

I have no idea where the error is. Maybe I missed something.

Coordinates:

```
float[] positions = new float[] {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
```

Calculating the projection matrix:

```
 public static void createProjectionMatrix() {

    Vector2f windowSize = DisplayManager.getWindowSize();

    float aspectRatio = windowSize.x / windowSize.y;
    float halfWidth = 1.0f;
    float halfHeight = halfWidth / aspectRatio;

    float left = -halfWidth;
    float right = halfWidth;
    float bottom = -halfHeight;
    float top = halfHeight;
    float far = -1f;
    float near = 1f;

    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

    matrix.setIdentity();

    matrix.m00 = 2f / (right - left);
    matrix.m11 = 2f / (top - bottom);
    matrix.m22 = -2f / (far - near);
    matrix.m32 = (far + near) / (far - near);
    matrix.m30 = (right + left) / (right - left);
    matrix.m31 = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);

    projectionMatrix = matrix;
 }
```

Calculation the transformation (Vector2f worldScale is not used):

```
private Vector2f getDisplayCoords(Vector2f percentage) {
    Vector2f v = DisplayManager.getWindowSize();
    return new Vector2f(v.x * percentage.x, v.y * percentage.y);    
}

public void loadTransformationMatricies() { 
    Vector2f displaySize = getDisplayCoords(size);
    Vector2f displayPos = getDisplayCoords(position);
    Vector2f display = DisplayManager.getWindowSize();

    Vector2f worldPos = Mouse.getWorldPos(displayPos);
    Vector2f worldScale = new Vector2f(displaySize.x / (display.x / 2.0f), displaySize.y / (display.y / 2));

    float x, y;
    x = worldPos.x;
    y = worldPos.y - CORNER_SCALE;
    //y is calculated correct. Moving the mouse to the same y value as calculated shows that everything is correctly calculated
    System.out.println(y + " | " + Mouse.getWorldPos().y);
    transforms[0] = Maths.getTransformationMatrix(new Vector2f(x, y), new Vector2f(CORNER_SCALE, CORNER_SCALE));
}
```

Check size:

```
GLFW.glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(WINDOW, new GLFWWindowSizeCallback() {

        @Override
        public void invoke(long arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
            resized = true;
        }
});
```

Rendering (would normally render more objects):

```
@Override
protected void render() {
    shader.start();
    if(DisplayManager.isResized()) {
        shader.loadProjectionMatrix(MasterRenderer.getProjectionMatrix());
    }
    bindModel(Loader.getQuad(), new int[] {0});
    for(GUI gui : guis) {
        if(DisplayManager.isResized()) {
            gui.loadTransformationMatricies();
        }
        bindTexture(gui.getTexture().getTopLeftCorner(), GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        Matrix4f[] transforms = gui.getTransformations();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transforms[i]);
            drawSTRIP(Loader.getQuad());
        }
    }
    unbind(new int[] {0});
    shader.stop();
}
```

Vertexshader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 position;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec2 textureCoords;

void main (void){

    gl_Position =  projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 0, 1.0);
    textureCoords = vec2((position.x+1.0)/2.0, 1 - (position.y+1.0)/2.0);
}
```

You can find the whole code on Github if you need more information but I only want to know how to fix this specific problem.
https://github.com/StackOverflowEx/GameEngine2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the size of the window has changed, the viewport rectangle has to be adjusted to the new size:

Use [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) to set the viewport rectangle.

Add a method `updateViewPort` to the class `DisplayManager`

```java
public static void updateViewPort() {
    IntBuffer pWidth = stack.mallocInt(1);
    IntBuffer pHeight = stack.mallocInt(1);

    GLFW.glfwGetFramebufferSize(WINDOW, pWidth, pHeight);
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, pWidth.get(0), pHeight.get(0)); 
}
```

Call the `DisplayManager.updateViewPort` in  the method`prepare` in the class `MasterRenderer`:

```java
private void prepare() {

    if(DisplayManager.isResized()) {
        DisplayManager.updateViewPort();
        createProjectionMatrix();
    }
    Camera.calcViewMatrix();

    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

See also [Java Code Examples for org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetFramebufferSize()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW&method=glfwGetFramebufferSize).